# How to call a function after a bind javascript

Tags: javascript, epub, tableofcontents

Good day all,
Please I need help in resolving a situation where I want to call a function after an epub has fully loaded.

The code below loads the epub successfully, but I would like to display the table of contents (toc), which actually shows in developer console after the epub file has loaded.
I've not been able to make the toc to display, the LoadToc is never called, and when I change where it is being called, it is called immediately, without waiting for the epub to fully load.

```js
book = null;
document.getElementById('bookChooser').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  var firstFile = e.target.files[0];
  if (window.FileReader) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      book = ePub({
        bookPath: e.target.result
      });

      book.renderTo("area");
      /* Replace area with the id for your div to put the book in */

    }.bind(this).bind(this.LoadToc);

    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(firstFile);
  } else {
    alert("Your browser does not support the required features. Please use a modern browser such as Google Chrome, or Mozilla Firefox ");
  }
});

function LoadToc() {
  if (book !== null) {
    var results = book.toc;

    var $select = document.getElementById("toc"),
      docfrag = document.createDocumentFragment();

    var $select = document.getElementById("toc"),
      docfrag = document.createDocumentFragment();

    results.forEach(function(chapter) {
      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.textContent = chapter.label;
      option.ref = chapter.href;

      docfrag.appendChild(option);
    });

    $select.appendChild(docfrag);
    $select.onchange = function() {
      var index = $select.selectedIndex,
        url = $select.options[index].ref;
      display(url);
      return false;
    };
  }
}

document.getElementById("prev").onclick = function() {
  book.prevPage();
}

document.getElementById("next").onclick = function() {
  book.nextPage();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/epub.js/0.2.13/epub.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="bookChooser">
<select id="toc"></select>
<div id="area"></div>
<button id="prev" type="button"><</button>
<button id="next" type="button">></button>
```

Comment: What do you try to accomplish with `.bind(this).bind(this.LoadToc);` (which doesn't make any sense o.O)

Comment: I made you a snippet

Comment: Just add `book.renderTo("area");  LoadtToc()`

Comment: @Andreas, please don't mind me, I was trying to do a double bind, as I saw in a post, but it doesn't work in my case. I want to call LoadToc() after the the epub is fully loaded.

Comment: Hi @mplungjan, thanks for the edit. The toc is still not loaded at that point where book.renderTo("area"), I've tried it before. If you look at the developer console, the toc property does not show yet. But after the bind(this) is called, and you check the developer console, you will see the toc property under book object

Comment: You might want to add this script to make it work: <script src="https://unpkg.com/epub.js@0.2.15/build/libs/zip.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Ok finally I was able to resolve the issue.
The file reader needed to end before calling the function. So using the code below solved the problem.

```
  ...
  if (window.FileReader) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      book = ePub({
        bookPath: e.target.result
    });

    book.renderTo("area");
    /* Replace area with the id for your div to put the book in */

  }.bind(this).bind(this.LoadToc);

  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(firstFile);

  reader.onloadend = () => {
    LoadToc();
  }
} else {
  alert("Your browser does not support the required features. Please use a modern 
  browser such as Google Chrome, or Mozilla Firefox ");
}
...
```

For anyone that could be facing issues like this
Thanks to everyone that commented